# What is the error causing my character delay its response when press a key?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have some problems with my character's walking command. It delays its movement for a bit before it actually moves. And then at times it completely ignores the command to stop walking when I released the key.

**Code:**

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

hero.gotoAndStop(1);

var rightPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var leftPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var upPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var downPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false)
var heroSpeed: Number = 10;
var keys: Array = [];

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

function keyDownHandler(KeyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
        rightPressed = true;
    } else if (keys[Keyboard.LEFT]) {
        leftPressed = true;
    } else if (keys[Keyboard.DOWN]) {
        downPressed = true;
    } else if (keys[Keyboard.UP]) {
        upPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(KeyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
        rightPressed = false;
        hero.gotoAndStop(4)
    } else if (keys[Keyboard.LEFT]) {
        leftPressed = false;
        hero.gotoAndStop(2)
    } else if (keys[Keyboard.DOWN]) {
        downPressed = false;
        hero.gotoAndStop(1);
    } else if (keys[Keyboard.UP]) {
        upPressed = false;
        hero.gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}

function gameLoop(loopEvent: Event): void {
    if (rightPressed) {
        hero.x += heroSpeed;
        hero.gotoAndStop(8)
    }
    if (leftPressed) {
        hero.x -= heroSpeed;
        hero.gotoAndStop(6)
    }
    if (downPressed) {
        hero.y += heroSpeed;
        hero.gotoAndStop(5);
    }
    if (upPressed) {
        hero.y -= heroSpeed;
        hero.gotoAndStop(7);
    }
}
function onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

function onKeyUp(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}
```

**Warnings:**

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 68, Column 10   Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onKeyDown event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'keyDown', callback_handler).

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 72, Column 10   Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onKeyUp event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'keyUp', callback_handler).
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the two extra `KeyboardEvent` handlers (`onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown`), and move the code you have there into `keyUpHandler` and `keyDownHandler`. That will solve those migration warnings (because onKeyUp and onKeyDown were special methods in AS2), and it may be the solution to your other problem: I guess sometimes the `onKeyDown` handler gets executed after `keyDownHandler`, which means the boolean values in your array are not set yet and no movement will start.

Even better: also get rid of the array with booleans (and keys! you're abusing an Array for Dictionary use) and do it like this:

```
function keyDownHandler(KeyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    //etc    
}
```

Comment: Can you go into details on what I should be doing? You said to move the code I have there into 'keyUpHandler' and 'keyDownHandler' , however, what code were you preferring to to be put into 'keyUpHandler' and 'keyDownHandler' ?